# First next/previous substring positions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a long string, for instance:

```
var sentence = "Marry had a little lamb, Peter had a little wolf, the wolf ate the little lamb and the little wolf was happy.";
```

I need to find the position of the substring "Peter" inside the string.

That, of course, is `var pos = sentence.indexOf("Peter");`.

But now I have a problem - I need to find the *last* occurrence of the substring "lamb" `before` `pos` and the *first* occurrence of the substring "wolf" *after* `pos`.

How do I do that? Pure Javascript please, no jQuery.

Comment: jQuery would not help here anyways since you are not working with the DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
var pos = sentence.indexOf("Peter");
var pos2 = sentence.lastIndexOf("lamb", pos);
var pos3 = sentence.indexOf("wolf", pos);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZqsfZ/

The key here is the `fromIndex` parameter of `lastIndexOf`. It'll allow you to search the string (backwards) for the first occurrence of the word, from the specified index.

See the documentation for [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: +1 for links to documentation at dev mozilla and not w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sentence = "Marry had a little lamb, Peter had a little wolf, the wolf at the little lamb and the little wolf was happy.";
var pos = sentence.indexOf("Peter");
var last_lamb = sentence.substr(0,pos).lastIndexOf("lamb");
var first_wolf = sentence.indexOf("Peter", pos);
```